# cassandra composite, compund keys on multi node

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I'm doing some performance tests with different designs in cassandra recently. 
I'm currently using cassandra as write-intensive project. However, I'm going to add read-intensive part to export data with use of `select` statement.

I'm doing time series with the following table;

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  date text,
  n int, // it could be 1,2,3
  id timeuuid,
  PRIMARY KEY ((date, n), id)
);
```

I have `date|n` as the partition key. To improve read performance, I'm trying to gain leverage from the concept of wide rows. In the documentation, it is stated that;

If the partition key's are same, they're inserted to the same physical node with widening the partition key's row.

Therefore, I use `n` to evenly distribute the rows in case of getting  hotspots which is stated [here](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/08/14/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-2/);

However, in a multi-node cluster, when I insert the following;

```
'2013-07-30'|1, some-timeuuid 
'2013-07-30'|1, another-timeuuid
```

I see that they're not in the same physical node.

I get the node info by;

`nodetool getendpoint keyspace columnfamily some-timeuuid`

So, somehow I want them to be in same row to improve read performance, but not too wide in case of getting 2 billion columns. (which is the size limit of columns)

So, any ideas what's going on here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If am not mistaken, in order to find out in which nodes your rows are stored, you would need to run:

`nodetool getendpoints keyspace columnfamily 2013-07-30:1`

Use your (composite partition/) row key instead of your column key.

If you are using the SimpleStrategy for token/replica calculation, this will happen internally:

> You compute the MD5 hash of the key. Create sorted list of tokens
>   assigned to the nodes in the ring.  Find the first token greater than
>   the hash. This is the first node. Next in the list is the replica,
>   which depends on the RF.

(found this on the cassandra mailing list
 http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/How-to-find-what-node-a-key-is-on-td6202253.html)

(Updated my answer according the comment.)

Comment: The composite separator is :, and you shouldn't put quotes round the string since they'll be included in the key.  So the first example should be `nodetool getendpoints keyspace columnfamily 2013-07-30:1`.

Comment: Apparently, `nodetool getendpoints` also gives output for non-existing keys. It outputs the physical node ip after running an algorithm on key. you're right about the usage of `getendpoints`